# reading characters in a file using D language

Tags: file, io, char, d, counting

I am having a problem with an error I cannot figure out.  The purpose of my program is count the characters in the file "test" But I keep getting this error "function core.stdc.stdio.getc (shared(_IO_FILE)* stream) is not callable using argument types (File)"

Here is my code:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.file;
import std.string;
import core.stdc.stdio;




void main()
{

    char ch;
    int charCount;



    File file = File("test.txt","w");

    file=File("test,txt","r");

    while(!file.eof())
    {

        ch = getc(file);
        charCount++;

    }



    file.close();




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std.stdio.File` is not a C file handle, but you are using `getc` from the C library which expects one.

The easiest way is using [readText from std.file](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_file.html#.readText), which reads the whole file at once:

```
int count = "test.txt".readText.length;
```

Since it returns an array of characters, you can just take the length of that array to get your count.